# do ... while loop isn't working in main

Tags: c, loops, scanf

I wrote a simple program with a function that calculates the area of a circle. 
The program also asks to the user if he wants to calculate it again and if the input is `'N'`, the program is supposed to stop.

Here's the narrowed down test case:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main(void)
{
    float r;
    char f;  
    do {    
        printf("Type the radius\n");
        scanf("%f", &r);
        printf("Repeat? [Press N for stop]");
        scanf("%c", &f);
    } while(f != 'N');
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

but the loop never stops as it was intended to.

Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: What exactly does "not working" mean?

Comment: @KaranMer It's there. Look close, the indentation is a little challenging :D

Comment: @KaranMer At the end of the loop like it's supposed to be?

Comment: Tell him to align prooperly atleast

Comment: Yes sorry, next time I'll put a better indentation

Comment: Now it looks how the question should look like :)

Comment: Thank you LihO for helping me with the indentation and the look, I'll keep in mind this formatting rules :)

Comment: Just always try to localize the problematic part on your own so that once you ask, you can provide minimal test case that shows the buggy behavior.

Comment: Actually the perfect question would continue with your own effort that would show how you tried to solve this problem, e.g. "I put a break point at the second `scanf`, but the when I enter N, the value of `f` is changed to `\n` but I don't understand why this is happening"... something like that :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
scanf("%c", &f);
```

leaves a newline character in the input stream which is consumed in the next iteration. Add a space in the format string to tell scanf() to ignore whitespaces.

```
scanf(" %c", &f); // Notice the space in the format string.
```

Comment: Thank you KingsIndian, very useful :)

Comment: I face another problem here...
when I input number, it gives runtime error :/
what can I do??

Comment: @Anklon `scanf()` is generally not very good for handling *incorrect* inputs. The best you can do is to check for the return value: `if (scanf(" %c", &f) == 1) {/* input reading was successful */} else { /* input failure */}`. scanf() returns the number of inputs scanned successfully.

Comment: thats useful
but I just want to know , why in my case it cause runtime error when others not??Can it be any problem with my compiler
I use visual studio 6

Comment: @Anklon What do you mean by runtime error? what's ur input and how's it failing?

Comment: If I put any number(float/intiger)...it says
Debug error!
.........(location of the file)
runtime error

Comment: @Anklon I am not sure as I am not familiar with visual studio. But scanf() expects a *char* for the format `%c`. Technically anything other than  a char is [undefined behaviour](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) in C.

Comment: @KingsIndian
actually it happens to the first scanf()
`scanf("%f", &r)`
second scanf() don't get the chance to evaluate

Answer (score 2):

replace

```
scanf("%c", &f);
```

with

```
f=getch();
```